# composer discard changes: what do the [y,n,v,d,s,?] do

Tags: composer-php

Simple question that's been bugging me for months.

Occasionally I'll dive into the vendors directory to fix a bug (especially for our internal libs). After migrating and deploying the fix back to the source package, I'll `composer update company/package` in the main project and am asked:

```
Discard changes [y,n,v,d,s,?]
```

I have a decent grasp on `y` and `n` but haven't been able to find documentation about what `v`, `d`, `s`, `?` do? I always hit `y` but maybe I'm missing out on something useful.

---

Edits:

- added `d` option (oct '17)

Comment: Have you tried using `?`? This will probably bring up a nice help message.

Comment: Sure. Things is it takes about two minutes for composer to do the update, recognize the dirty state and when doing actually work muscle memory kicks in I hit `y` and have no ability to hit `?` without waiting another couple of minutes. I figure if I'm scratching my head others are too.

Comment: this has got to be one of the misleading messages i've ever seen "updated, discard changes"? yes actually does not disccard changes and no actually does. wtf

Answer (score 236, accepted):

Choosing `?` shows you the details:

```
y - discard changes and apply the update
n - abort the update and let you manually clean things up
v - view modified files
d - view local modifications (diff)
s - stash changes and try to reapply them after the update
```

You can also check the source code, the relevant part is [here](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/f05e78aa9ee48a317142543da8b9c02613951273/src/Composer/Downloader/GitDownloader.php#L281-L320).

Comment: how to reapply the stash ?

Answer (score 46):

If you run with the `--no-interaction`, you can set `discard-changes: true` in `composer.json` file and you wont get prompted for this option every time.

Or, run:

`COMPOSER_DISCARD_CHANGES=true composer install --no-interaction`

Comment: Is there anyway to make this option kick in without running with `--no-interaction`

Comment: @JakeSylvestre maybe a year late, but this might be useful for others with similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18812171/1097372

Comment: @lyas Ah, great!  Thanks.

Comment: There is env var to control discard-changes
`COMPOSER_DISCARD_CHANGES=true composer install --no-interaction`